# Centos7, file access error "No such file or directory", but can copy and stat

Tags: linux, file, filesystems, centos7

Have a lab Centos 7.1(kernel 3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64) installed in Virtualbox 5.2.18, host is Windows 10. This VMs was install months ago and recently I power it up and found an issue which I hope to understand and learn to resolve.

in the /root folder there are 2 text files, only one of them got this issue.;
1) can't "cat", vi, 'more' or 'less' the file, error is => "dir: cannot access a: No such file or directory"
2) can be copied, via 'cp', but the copied file also got this same issue. The copied file can be deleted. 
3) The command "file" and "stat" output look normal to me.

I created a new file called *test2.txt*, in the same folder and it didn't experience this issue. Below screenshot show both file using Stat. The file with issue is "test.txt"

[Stat output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9z3N.jpg)

Guess it is hard link issue, I was testing that months ago.
Please share is there step or guide to troubleshoot this issue. Thanks!